# Random selection and conditional probability question.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Say in Silicon Valley, 35% of engineers program in Java and 28% of the engineers who
program in Java also program in C++. Furthermore, 40% of engineers program in C++.

a. What is the probability that a randomly selected engineer programs in Java and C++?

b. What is the conditional probability that a randomly selected engineer programs in Java
given that they program in C++?

For A, I got 35 * 0.28 = 9.8.

B is what I'm confused by. How do I calculate a conditional probability that a randomly selected engineer programs in Java given that they program in C++? Is this using Bayesian Theorem?

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability: $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$

Comment: @dromastyx thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is pretty much the same as

[Is there a formula I can use to solve this probability problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644177/is-there-a-formula-i-can-use-to-solve-this-probability-problem/3644241#3644241)

it involves Bayes theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

https://youtu.be/HZGCoVF3YvM from 3Blue1Brown